# Auto creating accounts

Tags: login, authentication, ldap

I'm wondering if there is any way to configure Ubuntu or install special software which could allow to automatically create user account when user login first time (without any special privileges, only standard user). 
The scenario is to allow any user which has physical access to computer to login on it (with GUI). Using guest session is not enough because each user should has it's own profile and folder.

I know there is a way combined with LDAP authentication for creating accounts and home folders for valid users. I would prefer to not use LDAP mechanism because I want skip process of setting up accounts for each user on LDAP server.

I do not expect full solution (but if someone accidentally has sth like that it could be nice:)) maybe some tips what tools or system modules could I use/modify to achieve this.

I will be grateful for any help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Linux isn't meant for that, it would require modifying login scripts. Easiest way would be to make www site with option to add users.