# Use Google Open ID to automatically create accounts/login to Ubuntu

Tags: login, chromium, authentication, accounts

What I'd love to be able to do is to have the ability to use Google's Open ID system to have users automatically authenticate with Ubuntu.

Yes, it would be Chromium OS-like in its login but there are three problems:

1. Chromium OS doesn't work (yet) on the laptops I'm setting up with Ubuntu so it's not even an option;
2. Chromium OS is quite unstable; and,
3. Chromium OS doesn't run proprietary Windows plug-ins through Wine (we need Macromedia and Silverlight in a big way for many of the sites we access).

A similar question ([Auto creating accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516363/auto-creating-accounts)) popped up about auto-creating login accounts with a categorical "no" but I find that hard to believe that it's impossible to automate account creation... how are the various system accounts created at install? :)

PS I'm specifically asking about Google's implementation of Open ID because that's what our group's accounts are.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://code.google.com/p/pam-openid/

Comment: @muru: empty and just a placeholder for a blog...  :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found something [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cipher.googlepam/1.6.0) but it comes with a few warnings:

- Never install a PPA just because someone tells you (including me) PPA's are one vector to get malware on your PC.  *Use your own [personal judgement!](https://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/)*

  That being said, a PPA with 1000s of users like PPA:Launchpad/TuxOnIce is a bit better then PPA:Maffia.It/BotNet with a couple of 100 users.
- The technology looks sound, but I have my personal reservations on allowing internal machines on your internal network to be authenticated by an external server: too many vectors for a [**Man-in-the-middle Attack**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
- The PAM above is written in Python, an interpreted language with full source code available to the end-user, so [harden not only the server **but also the clients**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/harden).
- I could go on and on like this, but then it would sound more like consultancy (thus work)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Not sure if it works yet because I'm stuck on figuring out the values of various flags (e.g. DOMAIN, USER, PASSWORD). I've tried a domain for which I am the admin with no success--I cannot figure out how to enter the user/password to get an authentication. Plus, I don't think this would be suitable since I am not the admin for our org's domain and I don't want ALL accounts (+I'm sure they wouldn't give me the password for such a project :). I did notice a discussion from 2010 describing what I'd like to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560965/openid-pam-module

Comment: Hopefully the code from Chromium OS will eventually allow for the creation of such an authentication mechanism for login (& automatic account creation) to Linux. I certainly lack the coding skills to adapt Chromium's code to Linux :(

Comment: And something like that would definitely fall outside the scope of AskUbuntu...  ;-)